# Symfony DQL syntax error

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to do DQL query, but having some troubles with it...

```
$user = $this->getUser();

$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p
       FROM AppBundle:User u
         JOIN AppBundle:Follower f
         JOIN AppBundle:Photo p 
           WHERE u.id = :id
           AND f.follower_id = :id
           AND p.user_id = f.user_id'
)->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
```

I am trying to get Photos (`AppBundle:Photo`) of those users, to whom the logged user is following.

Getting next error:

```
`[Syntax Error] line 0, col 128: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'p'`
```

Whats wrong here with 'p' ?

Comment: `p` is the table alias, try to select `p.*`. But I think Doctrine will not allow you to select something that does not contain at least your main table, i.e. `u.*`

Comment: I dont need Users info. What will be the correct dql then?

Answer (score 1):

*I don't understand why `follower` are in your code, I don't see relation with `photo`...*

*After, I think you call `Join` but I don't see the relation you made with the photo...*

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p
  FROM AppBundle:Photo p       
     JOIN p.user u
       WHERE u.id = :id ')->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
```

Here is a part of the [official doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#joins) :
Example:

> Regular join of the address:
>
> createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u JOIN u.address a
>   WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'"); $users = $query->getResult();
>
> Fetch join of the address:
>
> createQuery("SELECT u, a FROM User u JOIN
>   u.address a WHERE a.city = 'Berlin'"); $users = $query->getResult();

Comment: The task is: Get photos of THOSE users, to whom current user is following.

Comment: So first of all i need to Join with Follower to get all followers then join Photo to get photos

Answer (score 0):

did yu try this?:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
'SELECT p
  FROM AppBundle:Photo p       
     JOIN AppBundle:Follower f
     JOIN  AppBundle:User u
       WHERE u.id = :id
       AND f.follower_id = :id
       AND p.user_id = f.user_id' )->setParameter('id', $user->getId());
```

Comment: I did, i have almost same error - [Syntax Error] line 0, col 128: Error: Expected =, <, <=, <>, >, >=, !=, got 'u'

Comment: try this: select p,f,u from etc etc ... ?